# Node.js redirecting GET request loses Origin header

Tags: node.js, cors, http-headers

My Node.js application uses this function to redirect GET requests to specific URLs:

```
function forwardGetRequest(req, res, url){
    res.redirect(url);
}
```

However, when I use this in conjunction with JavaScript/AJAX requests on my webpage, I get the following error:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

I have already set up my domain correctly in my application, with regards to CORS, but the issue here is that **this redirect does *not* forward the Origin in the headers**.

To prove this point, when I directly make a request to 'url' from the AJAX request, instead of proxying through the Node.js application, the Origin is correctly set in the header and I get the correct response.

Comment: you want to forward to outside (not within your app) URL?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Not at the moment (although that's possible in future). Essentially I am forwarding to the same URL but a different port.

Comment: Is the request your client side JS is making to your end point that issues the redirect **same origin** or **cross origin**?

Comment: @Quentin It's all the same origin. It's just that it gets lost from the header upon redirecting

Comment: @HomerPlata - "Essentially I am forwarding to the same URL but a different port" — Your two servers are different origins to each other. Are either of them the same origin as the request is coming from?

Comment: @Quentin The request is on [domain]:443, the Node.js application is running on [domain]:9001 and it is redirecting to [domain]:9006

Comment: did anyone find a way how to pass origin with redirect ? :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below code ?

```
const http = require('http');

function forwardGetRequest(req, res, url){
    const baseUrl = "" // change port here
    var connector = http.request({
        host: baseUrl,
        path: req.url,
        method: req.method,
        headers: req.headers // don't forget to add headers
    }, (resp) => {
        // check resp here.
        resp.pipe(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've previously had it working by piping the request through, but it's not a proper redirect. I want to use the redirect functionality instead of piping requests through as a proxy.